# how to rewrite this php "if" statement without the deprecated "each" function?

Tags: php, each

How can I rewrite this piece of php script to not use the deprecated function 'each' anymore in the 'if' statement ?

```
if (list($_basic_auth_realm, $_basic_auth_header) = each($_auth_creds))
{
     ...
}
```

Many thx in adv. for you input !

V.

[EDIT]. This if statement is not in a loop. It's part of an larger block:

```
if (!empty($_basic_auth_header))
    {
    ....
    }
    else if (!empty($_basic_auth_realm) && isset($_auth_creds[$_basic_auth_realm]))
    {
    ....
    }
    else if (list($_basic_auth_realm, $_basic_auth_header) = each($_auth_creds))
    {
    ....
    }
```

$_basic_auth_realm, $_basic_auth_header are strings
$_auth_creds is an array

I don't really understand how this 'if' statement works. I only attempt to update the script which returns warnings when executed. It is used as a php proxy on my NAS as was written by Abdullah Arif: https://github.com/emersion/phproxy

Comment: Is this in a loop? Use `foreach`

Comment: First, you need to understand what [each][1] does.  Then you need to replace it with similar logic.

It really depends on what is in `$_basic_auth_realm`, `$_basic_auth_header`, and `$_auth_creds`, and the intent of that `if` statement.


  [1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

Comment: Thx Daniel. Most samples found on the web with a 'each' statement are indeed in 'while' loops. In my case, I found this php script in a package for Synology (made by Abdullah Arif in 2007). I hoped there would be a way to rewrte this without a loop. And to be honnest, using list (x, y) = each( my_array ) is a bit wierd... I guess it returns false if my_array has not a length != 2

Answer (score 1):

Use your own variable to keep track of the current index in the array, rather than depending on the internal state of the array.

```
$auth_creds_index = 0;
...
    else if (list($_basic_auth_realm, $_basic_auth_header) = $_auth_creds[$auth_creds_index++])
```

Each place where you currently use `each($_auth_creds)` should use `$_auth_creds[$auth_creds_index++]`, they'll get successive elements of the array.

If you reassign the variable with a new array, you need to reset the variable back to `0`.

You could also define a class wrapper for the array that automates all this.

Comment: Thx Barmar, I have added a comment in my question. The if statement is not in a loop. I could rewrite the block to use a loop but hoped to have something in a single statement.